# How to define swagger polymorhpic subTypes & discriminator in swagger 2.x like we define @ApiModel in 1.5.x?

Tags: jackson, jax-rs, swagger, jersey-2.0

I am trying to upgrade from swagger-core 1.5.12 to 2.0.0-rc2. Unfortunately this is not recognizing @ApiModel. The structure is entirely different due to OpenAPI 3 standards and need to define the swagger documentation using @Schema.

However it is not clear how to define the polymorphic behavior to decorate @JsonSubTypes implementaion in swagger 2.x. Is there any documentation explaning this other than https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Annotations-2.X#schema

Answer (score 0):

Found more details here:

> Schema Object

https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.0.md#schema-object

> Discriminator Object

https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.0.md#discriminatorObject